# Upload a file using form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to post a picture to this website. Wondering why this is not working? The url is [imggmi.com](https://imggmi.com/)

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
var inp = document.getElementById('file');
const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer();
dT.items.add(new File(['/Users/mbp/Downloads/panda.jpg'], 'panda.jpg'));
inp.files = dT.files;
document.getElementById('upload_butt').click()
```

Comment: Is this a browser extension? Anyway, the `File` constructor doesn’t read a file from disk.

Comment: @Ry- I want to programmatically assign the file name and upload it. Is that possible?

Comment: Depends on whether your script has permission to do that. Regular webpages don’t (because then they could steal files without user consent). So: is this a browser extension?

Comment: @Ry-, I would say yes. This is just an example of what I am trying to do. I want to upload a file from my computer to website. I am using selenium to drive the browser, and this piece of js , I am trying to inject into document. It's not working apparently.

Comment: So you’re injecting this script into a page on `imggmi.com` itself?

Comment: In this example, yes. I can see the file object has the appended file info. Just trying to see if I can make it work. In my original scenario, it&#39;s an asp.net website. @Ry-

Comment: You’ve deleted the comment now, but why is it that `sendKeys` won’t work in the real scenario?